JWT token sent as cookie is being deleted when refreshing page (Next.js 14)
I'm using Django REST Framework as backend to handle login, if the user is verified, the service send a cookie with a JWT token. Frontend was build using Next.js 14 app-router The code below works, I can see the cookie set in my browser.
Login view:
class Login(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = Usuariso.objects.filter(email=email).first()

       ...

        key = os.getenv('JWT_KEY')
        token = jwt.encode(payload, key, algorithm='HS256')

        res = Response()

        res.set_cookie(
            key='jwt',
            value=token,
            httponly=True,
            secure=True,
            max_age=60*60*24,
            expires=60*60*24,
            path='/')
        res.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }

        return res

The problem occurs when I refresh the page, CSRF and JWT cookies are deleted. The code below fetch login API:
app/components/loginForm.js
const login = async () => {

        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                key: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
                credentials: 'include',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                })
            });

            if (response.ok) {
              console.log("it works");  
            } 
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)   
        }
    };

I have read about JWT, when setting httOnly to true, cookie can not be accessible from javascript, so I think I should not need an third party library  to commit this
What I have tried:
Setting httpOnlny and secure = False
Commenting out httpOnly and secure
Setting domain as 'localhost'
